# Writing multidimensional to CSV file

Tags: c++, arrays, csv, io

I have a rather large two-dimensional vector of strings I'd like to write to a CSV file but my code crashes when I write. Any suggestions?

```
if (outfile.is_open()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < width.size() - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows.size() - 1; j++) {
            outfile << cells[i][j] << ",";
        }
        outfile << endl;
    }
} else cout << "Unable to write.";
```

Declaration of width, rows and cell:

```
//Declare stuff
vector<string> rows, cols, width;
vector< vector<string> > cells;
string line;

//Open input file
std::ifstream infile("99-110.csv", ios_base::in);
std::ofstream outfile("99-110_corr.csv", ios_base::out);


//Create vector with each row as an index
while (getline(infile, line)) {
    rows.push_back(line);
    width = split(rows[0], ",");
}

//Split each vector index into a 2D vector
for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
    cols = split(rows[i], ",");
    cells.push_back(cols);
}
```

As it turns out I had rows.size() and width.size() mixed up. I swapped them and now everything seems to work for small files, but for files larger than around 500 MB my script crashes with *terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'*. It seems to be crashing during the for loop where I split each vector index into a 2D vector (last for loop provided above). The maximum size for the vector "cells" is 357,913,941 but I've calculated the actual size of the vector to be 97,780,085.

Comment: `Any suggestions?` use a debugger.

Comment: And `cells` really is an `width.size() * rows.size()` matrix? And the indexes are in the order in the code shown? Can you please show us the declaration and initialization of `width`, `rows` and `cells`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg edited as requested. The split function referenced above is simply parsing a csv file and splitting each row by the commas. So yes, I'm sure cells is of columns width.size() and rows rows.size().

Comment: uhmmm, wrong, you are changing width every time you put stuff in. you cannot be sure if it is the same size as `cells[i].size()`.

Comment: Right, but I know the amount of rows and columns will always be the same as the initial read. It's a square matrix.

Comment: also, you don't need `vector<string> rows, cols, width;` but just cells. all the other vectors should be function locals...

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need `rows, cols, width`? `cells` contains all the informations you need i suppose, so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cells.size(); i++) { // start from i=1 to skip header
    for (int j = 0; j < cells[i].size(); j++) {
```

you would read `cells` with something like:

```
while (getline(infile, line))
   cells.push_back(split(line, ","));
```